# Grep matching and looping through directory and store in different output files

Tags: shell, grep

I have 3 files as follows:

```
1.out
a 
b
c

2.out
g
h
abcd
a 
h

3.out
b
c
e
a
```

I need one line above and one line below in the file where the pattern 'a' matches and stored in the new corresponding file

```
for file in *.out;do grep -A 1 -B 1 'a' $file > $file_output.txt; done
```

Comment: So what is not working then

Comment: It is not storing in different file.It just creates one file $file_output.txt

Comment: Use the append operator `>>`, the `>` creates a new file every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` (underscore) is a valid character in a variable's name.

This means that `$file_output.txt` uses the variable `file_output` and appends the string `.txt` to its value.  If that variable does not exist, then you now have a file called `.txt`.

To tell the shell that the variable name ends before the `_`, use curly braces around its name:

```
"${file}_output.txt"
```

Also note the quoting of the variable expansion (will be needed if any file in the current directory has a whitespace in its name (`file 1.out`) or a filename globbing character (`[123].out` or `*.out` or similar)).

Final loop:

```
for file in *.out; do
    grep -A 1 -B 1 'a' "$file" >"${file}_output.txt"
done
```